# GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF in Gtk 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk, gtk3

I want to display an image in a treeview and I cannot find the GObject.TYPE_* constant that describes the GdkPixbuf. I have searched good two hours on google and only found that supposably in C its GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF. It's not Gdk.TYPE_PIXBUF, GObject.TYPE_PIXBUF, GObject.GDK_TYPE_PIXBUF. The Python Documentation is not very helpful and it seems that it is just generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say it is a list store:

```
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf

lv = Gtk.ListStore (str, GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf)
```

if libgtk-3.0-doc doesn't help you, go online : http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0
but devhelp should be enough with the help of help(object)

Comment: That looks like what I am searching for, thanks! I will try it and get back to you.